# how to read message from Kafka consumer after some time interval

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

In my Spring boot application I have kafka consumer class which reads message frequently whenever there are message available in the topic. I want to limit the consumer to consume message in every 2 hours interval time. Like after reading one message the consumer will be paused for 2 hours then again consumer another message.
This is my consumer config method :-

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> scnConsumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();

    // common props
    logger.info("KM Dataloader :: Kafka Brokers for Software topic: {}", bootstrapServersscn);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServersscn);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 7200000);

    // ssl props
    propsMap.put("security.protocol", mpaasSecurityProtocol);
    propsMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, truststorePath);
    propsMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, truststorePassword);
    propsMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, keystorePath);
    propsMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, keystorePassword);
    return propsMap;
}
```

then I create this container method where I setup rest of the kafka configuration

```
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    LOGGER.info("Setting concurrency to {} for {}", config.getConcurrency(), topicName);
    factory.setConcurrency(config.getConcurrency());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(cFactory);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(7200000);
    return factory;
```

using this code partitions is rebalanced every 2 hours, but its not reading message at all.
My kafka consumer method :-

```
@Bean
public KmKafkaListener softwareKafkaListener(KmSoftwareService softwareService) {
    return new KmKafkaListener(softwareService) {
        @KafkaListener(topics = SOFTWARE_TOPIC, containerFactory = "softwareMessageContainer", groupId = SOFTWARE_CONSUMER_GROUP)
        public void onscnMessageforSA20(@Payload ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record)
                throws InterruptedException {
            this.onMessage(record);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: why don't you write your own sleep/interval method while consuming?

Comment: means Thread.sleep or use scheduler in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to add `@KafkaListener` annotated method in `KmKafkaListener`so that Spring kafka will take care of calling it.

```
public class KmKafkaListener{

  @KafkaListener(topics = SOFTWARE_TOPIC, containerFactory = "softwareMessageContainer", groupId = SOFTWARE_CONSUMER_GROUP)
  public void onscnMessageforSA20(@Payload ConsumerRecord<String, Object> record)
                throws InterruptedException {
            this.onMessage(record);
        }
}
```

and initalize the bean this way

```
@Bean
public KmKafkaListener softwareKafkaListener(KmSoftwareService softwareService) {
    return new KmKafkaListener(softwareService);
}
```

Comment: there is no issue in bean creation and all that. Only thing I need to do is kafka configuration where every 2 hour interval consumer will consume message.